# dealing with Linq XML and complex queries

Tags: c#, xml, linq

this is quite a brainteaser to me:

Assume i have XML data similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<site>
<open_auction id="open_auction0">
  <initial>25.39</initial>
  <reserve>67.91</reserve>
  <bidder>
    <date>09/27/1999</date>
    <time>18:47:09</time>
    <personref person="person308"/>
    <increase>18.00</increase>
  </bidder>
  <bidder>
    <date>06/03/2000</date>
    <time>17:47:49</time>
    <personref person="person942"/>
    <increase>19.50</increase>
  </bidder>
  <bidder>
    ...
  </bidder>
  <current>202.39</current>
  <itemref item="item2"/>
  <seller person="person573"/>
  <annotation>
    <author person="person128"/>
    <description>
      <parlist>
        <listitem>
          <text>
            niece <keyword> till banqueting little unkindly </keyword> 
          </text>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
          <text>
            emilia jack standards  
          </text>
        </listitem>
      </parlist>
    </description>
    <happiness>1</happiness>
  </annotation>
  <quantity>1</quantity>
  <type>Regular</type>
  <interval>
    <start>12/23/2001</start>
    <end>11/11/2000</end>
  </interval>
</open_auction>
<open_auction id="open_auction1">
...
</open_auction>
<open_auction id="open_auction2">
...
</open_auction>
</site>
```

you can download a complete and much bigger (about 5MB) test-file from www.megamatz.de/auction.xml

I need to determine the IDs of all open_auctions where a certain given person (Person1) issued a bid before another given person (Person2). "Before" in the meaning of the the "bidder"node of Person1 occures before the "bidder"node of Person2 within one open_auction, so its not concerning date or time.

Here is the XPath-Query for this problem maybe it explains the problem better:

```
let $auction := doc("auction.xml") return
for $b in $auction/site/open_auctions/open_auction
where
  some $pr1 in $b/bidder/personref[@person = "person20"],
       $pr2 in $b/bidder/personref[@person = "person51"]
  satisfies $pr1 << $pr2
return <history>{$b/reserve/text()}</history>
```

I know somehow that i need some kind of nested queries, but I can´t get it straight with this Linq-concept and these XElement(s). So I am not only interested in a solution but also understanding the concept espacially of any(), contains() and what else there is to cope with queries like these with linq.

I am really desperate and need some help, I have been searching an trying the whole night long, but I simply can´t get it straight and nothing works.

**Edited to add**

I am sorry to ask again, but no, it doesn´t work. I have tried and tried, which was very good, because I have learned a lot of things. I have the feeling I am nearly finding the answer, but when it comes to the "ElementAfterSelf" there is something going on where I could use a little hint and explanaition in the context of this complex query.

Here is my approach, which I have figured out on the basis of what I learned from Jon Skeets answer:

```
List<XElement> = doc.Descendants("open_auction")
                 .Where(x => x.Element("bidder") != null && x.Elements("bidder")
                    .Any(b => b.Elements("personref")
                        .First(c => c.IsBidder("person540"))
                           .ElementsAfterSelf("bidder").Any(d => d.IsBidder("person1068"))
                         )).ToList();
```

But it doesn´t work either. But...:

```
List<XElement> j = XMarkXML.Element("site").Element("open_auctions").Elements("open_auction")
                 .Where(x => x.Element("bidder") != null && x.Elements("bidder")
                    .Any(b => b.Elements("personref")
                        .Any(c => c.IsBidder("person540")) //I changed First with Any
                     //.ElementsAfterSelf().Any(d => d.IsBidder("person1068")) //and commented the last part out
                         )).ToList();
```

... at least brought up the 3 "open_auction"s where "person540" is a bidder. To be specific in my testfile it is id="open_auction11" where "person1068" bidds "after" "person540".

I am asking from the bottom of my heart, can somebody please give it a try with the Testfile. I uploaded it to www.megamatz.de/auction.xml . Inside the file the path to the open auctions is: Element("site").Element("open_auctions").Elements("open_auction")

Comment: You've given a *massive* file, most of which is irrelevant as far as I can see. It would *really* help if you could include in your post a *simplified* form (containing only the elements which are actually relevant).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Okay, edited again. I *think* this is okay, but even with your sample file it would be nice if you could give us a concrete example of inputs and expected outputs:

```
// Extension methods
internal static bool IsBidder(this XElement bidder, string person)
{
    return (string) bidder.Element("personref")
        .Attribute("person") == person;
}

internal static IEnumerable<XElement> ElementsAfterFirst
    (this IEnumerable<XElement> source, XName name)
{
    var first = source.FirstOrDefault();
    if (first != null)
    {
        foreach (var element in first.ElementsAfterSelf(name))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}

var query = doc
    .Descendants("open_auction")
        .Where(x => x.Elements("bidder")
               // All the person20 bids...
               .Where(b => b.IsBidder("person20"))
               // Now project to bids after the first one...
               .ElementsAfterFirst("bidder")
               // Are there any from person51? If so, include this auction.
               .Any(b => b.IsBidder("person51"))
               );
```

The second extension method can also be written as:

```
internal static IEnumerable<XElement> ElementsAfterFirst
    (this IEnumerable<XElement> source, XName name)
{
    var first = source.FirstOrDefault();
    return first == null ? new XElement[0] : first.ElementsAfterSelf(name);
}
```

It changes the timing slightly, but it shouldn't make any difference in this particular case...

Comment: You can't do `.Any(b => b.ElementsAfterSelf("bidder").WithBidder("person51"))`, since it will return `IEnumerable<XElement>`. The `.Any` method expects a `bool`.

Comment: Btw the thing with the position and date/time is not important. I am challenging myself by trying to implement the XMark XML Benchmark (http://www.xml-benchmark.org/) in Silverlight to be able to compare the performance with other frameworks and to learn complex XML-handling with this Linq

Comment: Okay, have now edited significantly to simplify. Hopefully it works now :)

Comment: I think I found the problem, but don´t know how to solve it. testdata is still available at www.megamatz.de/auction.xml . In that exampeldata in open_auction11 person540 bids before person1068. The problem is that .Where(b => b.IsBidder("person20")) can be empty an then First() throws an error. Same with x.Elements("bidder") scince there are open_auctions where no bidds have been placed allready. I managed to check the x.Elements("bidder") as posted in my addition to my answer, but I dont get it right to check it out inside the => b.IsBidder("person20"))

Comment: @user938919: My code no longer uses First - it uses FirstOrDefault. Did you try the new code?

Comment: To be specific in my testfile it is id="open_auction11" where "person1068" bidds "after" "person540". I will check out the new code

Comment: @user938919: Just tried my code and it is indeed giving open_auction11.

Comment: perfect, thank you for testing!  But I am heaving problems with integrating the code in my project. But it gives me big hope that you succeded. Thanks alot. But what does this yield return do?

Comment: OK now I can name my problem somehow. I don´t know how to embed the // Extension methods
internal static ... methods. I am working in silverlight an the class, where I do my coding in starts with namespace SilverlightApplication3
{

    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {

Comment: @Jon: you went above and beyond with this one!

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot Jon! Your code helped me a lot to learn this concept of Linq to XML
Ok, I have made a query without any helper methods, which works fine. I have formated a bit unusal but it might help other noops like me who take a look here to understand what is going on:

```
 List<XElement> i = XMarkXML.Element("site").Element("open_auctions").Descendants("open_auction")
        .Where(x => (x.Element("bidder") != null )
                    &&
                    (x.Elements("bidder").Any(b => (b.Element("personref").Attribute("person").Value == "person540")))
                    &&
                    (
                      x.Elements("bidder").Where(
                                                 b1 => (b1.Element("personref").Attribute("person").Value == "person540")
                                                 ).First().ElementsAfterSelf("bidder").Any(
                                                                                            b2 => (b2.Element("personref").Attribute("person").Value == "person1068")
                                                                                            )
                    )
               ).ToList();
```

When taking actions on Collections, it is important, that there is something inside, so it is important to check if Collection.Count() != 0. After that it is possible to do the query.

Comment: Rather than checking for Count(...) != 0, it's generally better to use Any(...)